# How many 4 letter strings can be formed from a , b, c where the letter c has to appear at least twice

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

How many $4$ letter strings can be formed from `a, b, c` where the letter c has to appear at least twice.

I tried to find a similar problem but couldn't get an answer.

---

Edit:  I have a second, similar question.  How many $4$ letter strings can be formed from `a, b, c` where every `a` must be followed by `b`?

Comment: Just list the ways to put $c$s in by hand.  List all pairs, triplets, and fours.  You get a factor $2$ for each non$-c$  Yes, there are fancier ways, but for only four letters this works fine.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to calculate all possibilities mathematically

Comment: we have to fill 4 places with 4 letters. There can be two cases, 1) c's are indistinguishable or 2)  c's are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the number of strings that have `c` appearing at least twice is equivalent to calculating the total number of possible strings, less the strings where `c` appears once, then less the strings where `c` does not appear.

Since there are $3$ choices for each character in the string, there are $3^4=81$ total possible strings.  Then, there are $2^4=16$ strings that `c` does not appear, and for each of the $4$ positions that `c` can take if it were to appear once, the remaining three characters will be populated by either `a` or `b`.  The total number of these is $4\cdot2^3=32$.

Therefore, the total number of strings where `c` appears at least twice is $81-16-32=\boxed{33}$.

---

To answer the question in your comments, we can total all the strings where `a` appears $0$, $1$, or $2$ times.  It cannot appear $3$ or $4$ times since it won't fit in with the required `b`.

If `a` was to appear $0$ times, the four characters in the string can be either `b` or `c` for a total of $2^4=16$ strings.
If `a` was to appear $1$ time, it can appear in only the first, second, and third position.  It cannot appear in the fourth since it needs to be followed by `b`.  In each of these three cases, the two remaining characters can be either `b` or `c` for a total of $3\cdot2^3=24$ strings.
Finally, If `a` was to appear twice, there is only $1$ valid string, namely `abab`.

Therefore, the total number of strings where every `a` is followed by `b` is $16+24+1=\boxed{41}$.

Comment: Thanks. 
I have one more question if possible almost same question but:
All possible strings where every "a" is followed by "b"

Comment: Does this mean the string `cccc` is valid, since there are no `a`s followed by non-`b`s?

Comment: Yes it should be valid

Comment: Thanks, it looks so easy when you explain it. But I couldn't figure out a way to calculate it